# Увеличение количества падающих предметов через промежуток времени

Tags: actionscript

Здравствуйте! Такая ситуация есть предметы которые падают с определённой частотой, хочу сделать чтобы через определённый промежуток времени количество предметов увеличивалось. Сделал с помощью таймера чтобы увеличивалась скорость, а вот как количество увеличить чёт не соображу :) Подскажите пожалуйста!!

Вот код:

```
import flash.events.Event;
import flash.display.MovieClip;
import flash.events.TimerEvent;
var kadr = 0;
var speedX:Number=0;
var speedY:Number=5;
stage.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, poyavlenie);
function poyavlenie (e:Event)
{
    if (++kadr%90 == 0)
    {

    var yayc = new Yayc();
    var razb = new Razb();
    var coord:Array = [95, 255, 415, 565, 707];
    var toch:uint;
    toch = uint(Math.random() * coord.length);
    yayc.x = razb.x = coord[toch];
    yayc.y = razb.y = 195;
    yayc.xmov = razb.xmov = speedX;
    yayc.ymov = razb.ymov = speedY;
    razb.visible = false;
    addChild(yayc);
    addChild(razb);

    yayc.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, polet);
    razb.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, polet2);

    }
}

    var timer:Timer=new Timer(20000);
    timer.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER, timer_timer);
    timer.start();
    function timer_timer(e:TimerEvent):void
{
    speedX+=0;
    speedY+=5;
}
function polet (e:Event)
{
    var yayc = e.currentTarget;
    yayc.x += yayc.xmov;
    yayc.y += yayc.ymov;
    if (yayc.y>845)
    {yayc.removeEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, polet);
    removeChild (yayc);
    }

}

function polet2(e:Event)
 {
  var razb = e.currentTarget;
  razb.x += razb.xmov;
  razb.y += razb.ymov;
  if (razb.y > 845)
  {
   setTimeout(function():void
   {
    removeChild(razb);
   }, 70 * stage.frameRate);
   razb.removeEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, polet2)
   razb.visible = true;
  }  
 }
```

Comment: if (++kadr%90 == 0) - Да это промежуток между появлениями

Answer (score 1):

Видимо это условие отвечает за промежуток между появлениями:

```
if (++kadr%90 == 0)
```